# reRendering visualforce component fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

Not able to rerender objects on a Visualforce component's object. Have not had to rerender a component and have seen several variations on what I am trying to do.

The reRender="NSA1a,NSA1b,NSA1c" produces this error on the paretn Visualforce page:

```
ERROR: Could not resolve field 'Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c' from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!LOB.Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c}' in component c:prod_ccra_lob_nonstdauto
```

On the parent Viualforce page:

```
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto NonStdAuto="{!LOB_NonStdAuto}" record="{!Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c}" />
```

The Visualforce Component page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
  <apex:outputLabel value="Does Client perform adequate investigations to confirm coverage for driver and vehicle at issue?"  StyleClass="col1"   />
    <apex:actionRegion >                          
      <apex:inputField value="{!NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c}" styleClass="col2" > 
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="NSA1a,NSA1b,NSA1c" / >                    
      </apex:inputField>
      </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >                         
  <apex:outputLabel value=""   /> 
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
 <apex:outputPanel id="NSA1a">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Please comment as needed to describe the diligence of their coverage investigation:"  StyleClass="col4" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"   /> 

 </apex:outputPanel> 

 <apex:outputPanel id="NSA1b">                       
   <apex:inputField value="{!NonStdAuto.Comment_diligence_coverage_investigation__c}" styleClass="inputFieldStyle1" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"  />                  
 </apex:outputPanel>                                
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
  <apex:outputPanel id="NSA1c">                                               
    <apex:outputLabel value=""  rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"  />                                                
 </apex:outputPanel>                                    
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is not set because you're rendering only part of the component. To make your life less complicated, just change all of the `LOB` to `NonStdAuto`.

Comment: Changed references to LOB to NonStdAuto. Error is gone but now that fields do not render on .

Comment: @rickmac It might be During the original render or after reRender?

Comment: looks like the original rendering because when I just open the parent page the field is set to "Yes" and the expected field below is not rendered.

Comment: @rickmac it's just an `apex:outputLabel` with no value. There would be nothing to see...

Comment: the outputLabel contains input fields as well. I got this to work using this rendering syntax: rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(NonStdAuto.Client_perform_adequate_investigation__c,'Yes'),true,false)}"  Your initial suggestion re: variable state helped out as I'm using the attribute (NonStdAuto) and not the variable assignment (LOB.) I prefer a shorter rendering statement but it wasn't evaluating to a true/false.  Updating the source code above.